# Imageresizer: Red dot on images although I have purchased a license

Tags: imageresizer

I've purchase a Performance license and added it to web.config, but still have the red dot. Not sure if this is because I registered it for domain.com but am using it on www.domain.com

The diagnostic page tells me I have no license. Here's the output. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
0 Issues detected:

Assembly use report: 


You are using plugins and assemblies from the V4 Performance Edition.


----------------

License keys

You do not have any license keys installed.

----------------



Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]

Configuration:

<resizer>
<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true" />
<diagnostics enableFor="allhosts" />
<licences>
<license>

        tspc.co.uk(R4Performance includes R4Performance):RG9tY--lotsmorelicensestuff==
    </license>
</licences>
<plugins>
<add name="DiskCache" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/8.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.34014
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Installed HttpModules: 

System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlRoutingModule-4.0)
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under keyScriptModule-4.0)
System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyOutputCache)
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keySession)
System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyWindowsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFormsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyDefaultAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyRoleManager)
System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFileAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyAnonymousIdentification)
System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyProfile)
System.Web.UrlMappingsModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlMappingsModule)
ImageResizer.InterceptModule, ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null          (under keyImageResizingModule)

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34014 Info: 4.0.30319.34014
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34274 Info: 4.0.30319.34274
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34239 Info: 4.0.30319.34239
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34274 Info: 4.0.30319.34274
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 12.0.20806.33440 Info: 12.0.20806.33440
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34274 Info: 4.0.30319.34274
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34262 Info: 4.0.30319.34262
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34262 Info: 4.0.30319.34262
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot IIS using `iisreset`. The diagnostics page always fetches the latest info from Web.config, but the ASP.NET runtime and IIS often fail to detect file changes.

**Update: I missed it!**

Change `<licences>` to `<licenses>`, THEN reboot.

You were correct in purchasing the root domain; subdomains are included.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response. I've done that but now I'm starting to think I've made an error in registering the root domain. Here's the current debugger output.

Comment: Image resizer diagnostic sheet  www.tspc.co.uk 12/05/2016 15:57:11

2 Issues detected:

resizer configuration(Error): No license found for domain www.tspc.co.uk - features installed: R4Performance or R4DiskCache
   

resizer configuration(Error): No license found for domain new.tspc.co.uk - features installed: R4Performance or R4DiskCache

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted it! Who'd have thought it'd be down to a US/UK spelling issue!

By the way, nothing to do with my problem, but on your 'installing a license key' page you've got two closing </license> tags when the second should be </licenses>

cheers

Garve